# Drools: Joda DateTime comparison

Tags: java, jodatime, drools

I'm setting up some Drools rules which are time-dependent, i.e. if the supplied time is between, say 8am and 5pm, then a certain result needs to be returned. A different one should be returned outside these times.

The object I'm passing in has a Joda DateTime which I'm needing to use in the rule.

At the moment, my approach consists of trying to format this Joda DateTime object into a 24-hour numeric value which I can then use an integer comparison on (i.e. > 800 and < 1700). I couldn't think of any other way of doing it since I have searched for examples but found few mentions of timestamp comparison in Drools, unfortunately.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget Drools temporal operators and timestamps: these are meant to be used in combination with events - CEP (Complex Event Processing). Whatever your objects describe, you need to test a simple numeric value that just happens *to be derived* from a time-and-date value, which is secondary to your issue.

Best way I can think of is to write a Drools function along the lines of

```
function boolean isBetween( DateTime dt, int start, int end ){
    int hhmm = dt.hourOfDay()*100 + dt.minuteOfDay();
    return start <= hhmm && hhmm < end;
}
```

and use it in a constraint

```
GarlicBreadObject( $dt: itsDateTime, isBetween( $dt, 800, 1700 ) )
```

Comment: Splendid. Thank you!

Comment: Update: the function syntax had to change a little, but it was on the right track (split into two seperate functions):

    function boolean isBefore(DateTime dateTime, int checkTime) {
        int hhmm = dateTime.hourOfDay().get() * 100 + dateTime.minuteOfHour().get();
        return hhmm <= checkTime;
    }

    function boolean isAfter(DateTime dateTime, int checkTime) {
        int hhmm = dateTime.hourOfDay().get() * 100 + dateTime.minuteOfHour().get();
        return hhmm >= checkTime;
    }